How best to associate a complex style file with another variable in another layer
I use qgis styles which contain some complex Case statements based on arrays to display information about colour, size and symbols for displaying points. There are about 10 references to the field (which we can call "field1") within the statements and so to make this work with another variable I have to manually edit each of them before applying the style.
So, is there  a way of automating this to replace "field1" with "newfield" when the style is applied? I am aware of "with_variable,.." but haven't been able to implement this reliably and in any case it still requires at least one edit.

You still would need to define it at one place. But to make it dynamic you could define the same layer variable on all your layers and in your expression you can than dynamically access it using the attribute and var functions.
For example:

You have two point layers. Each have two features. Both have one numeric field. If the value is <= 10 you want to style the point blue otherwise it should be red.
On Layer 1 the field is called number so you define a layer variable number_field with a value number.

On Layer 2 the the field is called num so you define a layer variable number_field with a value num.

Now you style your layers dynamically using an expression like:

CASE WHEN  attribute(var('number_field')) <= 10 
    THEN 'blue'
    ELSE 'red'
END


You can also refer to variables using @,  like @number_field

Do you mean as in using @number_field instead of attribute(var('number_field') in the answer above?

you can write attribute(@number_field) instead of attribute(var('number_field')) - just some syntactic sugar
